# Cartopy: Find distance of geodetic/plane carree

Tags: python, cartopy, map-projections, great-circle, geodesic-sphere

I have 4 questions related to cartopy geoetics in various map projections. Here is my code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs


ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Robinson())

ax.set_global()
ax.stock_img()

ax.coastlines()

plt.plot([-0.08, 132], [51.53, 43.17], color='red',  transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.plot([-0.08, 132], [51.53, 43.17], color='blue', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

plt.show()
```

Two examples of this are below, 1) Robinson projection, 2) Mollweide projection.
[image]
[image]

**Questions**

1. Does the red curve always show the great circle route, i.e. the shortest path on any map projection?
2. How can I get the distance of the red geodetic and the blue plane carree? If so, then the distance of the red curve should be the same for any map projection, correct?
3. On my second image, why is the red curve wonky? Is it supposed to be like that?
4. Does the blue curve always show the direct path *on the map projection*? As if you physically had a map on a piece of paper and drew a path from point A to point B with a ruler. If so, then the distance of the blue curve should be different for different map projections, correct?

Comment: Why do you ask for the length of the red great circle path on the projection?

Comment: I am using this as a diagram/simulation for a mathematics paper. I am planning to calculate the theoretical distances for the blue line for various map projections using their projection formulas, and want to include the red great circle path for comparison.

Comment: Are you aware of the difference betw a projected path on the plot  (red line) and its real path on the earth surface?

Comment: Isn't the red line the real path (the great circle), and the blue line the loxodrome/rhumb line?

Comment: The red line is the projected path of the great-circle arc on the earth surface.

Comment: How about the blue line? Is that the loxodrome/rhumb line?

How can I find the distance using cartopy?

Comment: If you plot the blue line on `mercator` projection, it will represent a rhumb line. If you can extract vertex coordinates of it, you get the rhumb line coordinates data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230410/discussion-between-soysoy4444-and-swatchai).